# Vue.js 2.0 passing Auth::user() to children components in complex hierarchy

Tags: laravel, components, vue.js

I have this rather complex structure. Imagine a stackoverflow like site for Q&A:

```
app.js               //new Vue object <- receives Auth::user() object by AJAX

- Question.vue       //main component
-- AnswerList.vue    // a question has an answer-list
--- Answer.vue       // an answer-list has multiple answers
---- CommentList.vue // an answer has a comment-list
----- Comment.vue    // a comment-list has multiple comments
```

I want to pass the authenticated user to the components `Question`, `Answer` and `Comment`. But **NOT** to `AnswerList` and `CommentList`.

Is there a way to pass the `Auth::user` just to these components or
do I really have to add `authuser` object as a `props` to all the components in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Auth::user()` is stored on the root instance as `authUser` the simplest way to access it in your child components would be to use `this.$root.authUser`.

This way you're effectively using the root instance as a store.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beautiful. Ok now I understand how the data is shared between components!!

Answer (score 3):

Even though answer is accepted and OP found a satisfying solution I think it's important to suggest using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). It's a centralized data store that keeps data that can be shared between components. Also allows you to modify data in vuex store from all components in a structured and debugable way  which is not possible with accepted solution.

I understand it might be an overkill for OP needs but I still belive it's a better solution.